# Laravel node js - Webpack compile with error

Tags: laravel, webpack

I have this error when do the `npm run watch`. I'm new to all this and really need help.

```
ERROR in /app
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'sass-loader' in 'C:\Xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\desire-theme'

webpack compiled with 1 error
Notifications are disabled
Reason: DisabledForUser Please make sure that the app id is set correctly.
Command Line: C:\Xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\desire-theme\node_modules\node-notifier\vendor\snoreToast\snoretoast-x64.exe -appID "Laravel Mix" -pipeName \\.\pipe\notifierPipe-bbd06478-53fd-4a3c-995a-1aa70d87d0a4 -p C:\Xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\desire-theme\node_modules\laravel-mix\icons\laravel.png -m "Error: Error: Can't resolve 'sass-loader' in 'C:\Xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\desire-theme'" -t "Laravel Mix"
```

Comment: Did you try installing it? `npm i sass-loader --save-dev`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to add Sass compilation to your webpack.mix.js file ?

If you want to use external scss files into your laravel project, you will need to tell Laravel/Mix where to find those files, and where they should be saved. When running npm scripts (such as npm run dev, npm run watch or npm run prod) scss will be converted into valid css files during compilation process.

Here is an example of what your webpack.mix.js file should contain :

```
// webpack.mix.js
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.sass('src/yourCustomStyles.scss', 'public/yourCustomStyles.css');
```

Sass method definition in Laravel/Mix Api :

> mix.Api.**sass**(src: string, output: string, pluginOptions?:
> object, postCssPlugins?: AcceptedPlugin[])

More info :

https://laravel-mix.com/docs/main/sass

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).